# How to get the Span wide of a .txt data

Tags: java, arrays, string

I must create a method that counts the max span wide of the integer with the biggest span wide in a .txt data. For example **1, 4, 1**, 3, 5, 6, has a max span wide of 3 because the biggest span wide is between the number 1.

**4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4** has a span wide of 7. It counts from the first number to the last number of a number the biggest spawn wide is in the number 4.
Sorry for my english i hope you can understand what I mean. I developet this code, but didn´t know how to initialize the second array. I try to scan out every number in a array and thant to put the span wide in a second. After that i try to sort the second Array and return length-1 to get the biggest span wide.

```
public int Spannbreite() {
    File g = new File("C:/Users/angd6/Downloads/spannbreite.txt");
    b = new int[10000];

    try {
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (g);
        max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= b.length-1; i++) {
        b[i] = sc2.nextInt();

    }for (int k = 0; k <= b.length-1; k++) {
        for(int j = b.length -1; j == k; j--) {
            c = new int[1000];  
            c[k] = j;   
        if(max <= c[k]) {
            max = c[k];
        }
    }}
    sc2.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Datei nicht vorhanden");

    }return c[c.length-1];
}
```

Comment: how do you get this? `4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4 has a span wide of 7`

Comment: from the first 4 to the last 4. everytime it count from the first number to the last. But only the numer with the biggest span wide.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must create the C array before the for loop because if you do it that way you're going to override the information every time.
2. In the nested for loop, you must compare the actual number with the number in the tail. The condition shall be if (b[k].equals(j)). After that, you can compare the distance between the two numbers and change the max if is necessary.
3. Assign the max to the array in the C position. I mean put C[b] = max after the completion of the nested for loop with this you can know which number has the max wide span